# ガワネイティブ（WebView）だけでiOS、Androidの開発、保守（地図やカメラ等の機能を組み込む予定）をしていくのはやめたほうがいいでしょうか？

Tags: ios, android

私はこれまで、個人でiOSのアプリの開発をやっており、いくつか、リリースをしております。

ただ、Androidの開発経験がなく、かつ、ユーザーからの反応の中に、Android版がほしいという要望があります。

要望に答えられないまま、いつもモヤモヤした気持ちを抱いております。

※Androidの勉強をしたいという気持ちもありますが、仮に勉強しても、iOSとAndroid両方を一人でやるということを考えるとちょっと、非現実的かなと思ってます。人を雇うほど稼げているわけでもないので、当面は一人です。

そのため、次の開発からはガワネイティブ（WebView）で開発すれば解決するかなと考えております。

ガワネイティブなので、地図やカメラ等のiOS、Android独自の機能も使える？といった記事も見ましたため、すごくいいのではないかと思ってます。

調べている中でよくデメリットとして挙げられていたのは**動作速度の問題**でした。

ただ、学習コストが低い等のメリットなどもあるため、今後はこちらにシフトしようかと思ってます。

上記を踏まえて、ガワネイティブで今後、開発、保守をしていく中で、皆様のご意見、ご経験をお伺いしたく存じます。

ガワネイティブは便利ですが、実際は・・・といったことも多いように思えます。

次開発するアプリの方向性はまだ漠然としてますが、これまで開発していた機能などをざっと列挙します 
・GoogleMapで位置情報を表示させる  
・カメラで写真をとる 
・プッシュ通知を送る 
・Instagramとまでは行きませんが、写真メインのアプリ

アプリでユーザー数100万人獲得することを当面の目標（勿論それ以上のユーザー）としているため、それに耐えうるのかどうかという観点も含めて頂けると幸いです。

特に気になる点は**Webビューで開発していると、iOSでは上手く描画されているが、Androidでは描画されてないといったことやバージョン毎で苦しめられるといった点です。**

Answer (score 3):

AndroidアプリでWebViewを使うのであれば『アプリの対象バージョン』を決める際に注意した方が良いです。

AndroidのOSごとに下記のような違いがあります。

- Android4.3まではAndroid独自ブラウザベースのWebView
- Android4.4からはChromiumベースのWebView
- Android5.0からはWebViewがOSから切り離され、Google Playストア経由でのアップデートが可能となったため、各通信キャリアのOSアップデート対応を待つ必要がなくなった

まずは利用を考えているHTML5 APIが対応しているかどうか検証してみてはいかがでしょうか？

おっしゃる通り、Androidではバージョン毎に描画に問題があったり、JavaScriptの処理がうまく動かなかったりということがよく発生します。
この対応方法として、[CROSSWALK](https://crosswalk-project.org/)を利用することも考えられます。
※Android4.0以降を対象とした場合に利用できます。

これはアプリにWebブラウザを丸ごと組み込むようなものなので、アプリのサイズが大きくなるデメリットがあります。
また、ユーザがOSバージョンアップしたり、Google Playストア経由でWebViewをアップデートしたとしてもアプリは影響を受けません。

ただ、CROSSWALKを使えばレンダリング速度が必ず速いと言うわけではありません。
参考までに[私が以前検証した結果](http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2015/04/12/crosswalk-test/)を共有させて頂きます。

個人的にはフルネイティブで開発したとしても、OSごとの対応はたいてい必要になるので、
WebViewを使ったハイブリッドアプリを開発することで工数を削減するのはアリだと思います。

少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
WebViewでの開発、保守経験がないため、経験者からのご意見を伺えることは大変参考になります!
また、CROSSWALKもすごく興味深いです。

CROSSWALKについて調べているとやはり10MBくらいの容量が必要になるみたいですね。ひとつ懸念していることは容量が大きすぎて、アプリが落ちてしまうのではないかという点です。

いろんなアプリをいじっていて一番嫌だと感じるのはこれです。
落ちるアプリはとことん落ちます。

さいわい、私はこれまでアプリを作っていて落ちるという報告を聞いたことがなかったのであまり縁がなかったのですが、CROSSWALKとかを使うと、そういった点も考慮していかなくてはいけないでしょうか？


一般的にどれくらいの容量とかになると危ないのかといったことは私の中で、まだ経験不足なためわかりませんが、もしそのあたりの知見が御座いましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

もちろん、ユーザ毎に、空き容量などは変わっているので一概にはいえない問題かと思います。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。私の経験で言うと、Android4.0.4の端末では、快適な動作ではありませんでした。(WebSocketを使って、毎秒データを送るような要件だったからかもしれませんが…。) 実装する処理にもよるかと思うので、アプリのサイズがどの程度であれば良いかまでは難しいですね。ただ、Intelが進めているPJですし、Cordovaとの互換性も考慮して作られているので、ある程度、信用はできると思いますよ。具体的な数値を出せず、申し訳ないです。

Comment: とは言え、Android Studioでメモリ解析できますので、開発しながら定期的にメモリの使用状態を確認することをオススメします。また、思い出したので、余談ですが、Android5.0以降のOSから切り離されたWebViewを使うと、JavaScriptのalertやconfirmが表示されないバグが発生していますので(Google Playストアで配布されるバージョンによると思いますが)、CROSSWALKを使わないにしても、Androidの場合は厄介なことが多いです。